# .htaccess returning mod_rewrite redirect to the index page of the www folder of wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create "pretty urls for dynamically created pages. My desire is to render all pages from the index page.

I am working on my computer using wamp 2.5/apache 2.4.9

The `apache httpd.conf` is set to:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:7080
Listen [::0]:7080
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
ServerName localhost:7080
```

I have tried several different approaches which have resulted in everything from a blank page returning to a 404 error page. With the code below it returns to the `index.php` in the `/www/` folder in wamp.

This is my non-working `.htaccess` code:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Pages 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?topic=$1

# Rewrite to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:7080/demo [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.localhost:7080/demo/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The clupret line of code is this I believe:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?topic=$1`

which I am thinking is some sort of path issue but am not sure... any assistance would be appreciated.

The URL in the address is: `http://localhost:7080/demo/test` where `demo` is the site folder in the `wamp/www/`

`http://localhost:7080/demo/test/` (with the forward slash) returns a 404 error.

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and where is this htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava sry about that I thought I covered all the based... `http://localhost:7080/demo/test`

Comment: the `.htaccess` is in the `demo` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your htaccess is lacking a rewrite base.
   Just after: RewriteEngine on

   Add RewriteBase /demo/
2. It is strictly not allowing trailing slashes
   Replace this line: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?topic=$1
   withthis code:

   ## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?username=$1 [N,L]

This will allow urls ending trailing slashes to force back to your redirect url.

3. Remove this from the last line:

   http://www.localhost:7080.
   Leave it as just: /demo/$1 [r=301,nc]

The second to the last line is not doing a lot. You can do and I will advice you do away with it.

Please do remember that when leaving the localhost environment for an online host, replace all incidence of "/demo/" with just "/"

Your final htaccess should be someting like this:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /demo/

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Pages 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?username=$1 [N,L]

# Rewrite to www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Using the above code: `http://localhost:7080/demo/test`  redirects to `wamp/www/index.php` and `http://localhost:7080/demo/` fires off a redirect loop.

Comment: Well I tested the code with your very setting and http://localhost;7080/demo/test/ redirects to  http://localhost;7080/demo/ and  http://localhost;7080/demo/ redirects to  http://localhost;7080/demo/ maybe their is another redirection somewhere else in your code

Comment: thank you for testing... I will run the htaccess with only your code and post my results here. thanks again... much appreciate.

Comment: McFriend Oluwan ... Thanks, I've been out of town just got to test and it worked fine.... thanks for taking the extra time to run the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in `/demo/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo/

# Rewrite to www.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}:7080%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?topic=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that returned the `wamp/www/index.php` I had tried using the `RewrtieBase /demo/` and `RewriteBase /` earlier but not your other rules

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` and what is the full URL you entered?

Comment: Full URL `http://localhost:7080/demo/test` and the doc root `c:/wamp/www/` and the Server Name: `localhost:7080`

Comment: ok what happens when you enter: `http://www.localhost:7080/demo/index.php?topic=test` ?

Comment: `http://localhost:7080/demo/index.php?topic=test` without `www.` renders as it is suppose to

Comment: it returned the index to www again.... seems like a path issue somewhere but I can't figure it out

Comment: Test this in Chrome dev tool.

Comment: when I test `http://localhost:7080/demo/test` I get no errors... when I test `http://localhost:7080/demo/` I do get an undefined variable error on my jquery file... do you think we could move this to chat as requested by the script... I truly appreciate your assistance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83489/discussion-between-anubhava-and-petebolduc).